# Iterating over nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to iterate over this object containing a array of quests-objects. How would i be able to iterate over each key value pairs to for example return all quests which have the status "completed".

```
{
    "quests": [
        {
            "title": "A Rum Deal",
            "status": "COMPLETED",
            "difficulty": 2,
            "members": true,
            "questPoints": 2,
            "userEligible": true
        }
    ],
    "loggedIn": false
}
```

Comment: iterate or return?

Comment: I don't think you want to "iterate over each key value pairs". You want to iterate over the **elements** in the array. Key/value pairs are a feature of objects; elements are a feature of arrays. By the way, even if you did not know the word "filter", a Google search for `find matching object array javascript property` would have turned up an answer right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iterating you could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
object.quests.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.status === "COMPLETED") {
        // do something with the data
    }
});
```

For returning a selection with completed task, you could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var completed = object.quests.filter(function (a) {
    return a.status === "COMPLETED";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`Array.prototype.filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the elements which have 'completed' status - see demo below:

```js
var array={"quests":[{"title":"A Rum Deal","status":"COMPLETED","difficulty":2,"members":0,"questPoints":2,"userEligible":0},{"title":"A Rum Deal","status":"NOT_COMPLETED","difficulty":2,"members":0,"questPoints":2,"userEligible":0}],"loggedIn":1};

var result = array.quests.filter(function(e){
   return e.status && e.status === "COMPLETED";
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: What is the point of the `e.status &&` part?

Comment: check if `status` is a property of `e`

Comment: It's not necessary. If `status` is not a property of `e`, then `e.status` will be undefined, which will not equate with `"COMPLETED"`.

Comment: you are right, it has become a habbit for me to write that check :)

Answer (score 1):

That's what [JavaScript filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) are for.

```
myObj.quests.filter(item => item.status === 'COMPLETED');
```